# How to remove backslash from JSON result in R

Tags: r

I tried making a JSON using JSONlite in R but the thing is, in the output, I could see backslash against each element of the json

```
result_list <- c()
_id <- c()
_name <- c()
_address <-c()

for (i in 1:10)){
 print(refdata$_name[i])
 _id<-append(_id,as.character(refdata$_Id[i]))
 _name < -append(_name,as.character(refdata$_name[i]))
 _address <-append(_address,as.character(refdata$_address[i]))
 }
result_list <- cbind.data.frame(_id,_name,_address)
y <- toJSON(result_list)


x <- list(is_success = "true",  
        result = y, message = "success", status_code = 200)
result_json <- toJSON(x)
```

But the output is showing the right output with additional backslach
JSON RESULT:
    ["{\"is_success\":[\"true\"],\"result\":[\"[{\\"portfolio_id\\":\\"5c3d894ca8c2f00071c20007\\",\\"_name\\":\\"Amit\\",\\"_address\\":\\"ABC\\"},{\\"_id\\":\\"5c3d88eba8c2f00071c1ffe7\\",\\"_name\\":\\"Rutul\\",\\"_address\\":\\"DEF\\"}]\"],\"message\":[\"success\"],\"status_code\":[200]}"]

How to get rid of backslash??

Comment: Please make your code reproducible. You don't provide `refdata`.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent I didn't get you. Do you mean should i add refdata also in the question for mroe information?

Comment: backslash are just there in console display to override `"` in print. If you print using say `jsonlite::prettify(result_json)` then they will not be there

Comment: @abhiieor I tried doing the same. But no success. Anyways thanks for help.